# Convert MS SQL Server Query in MYSQL QUERY

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database

I have written a Query,

```
SELECT dbo.boat.boatno, dbo.boat.boattype, dbo.staff.staffFirstName, dbo.staff.staffLastName,    
dbo.branch.branchAddress
FROM dbo.boat INNER JOIN
dbo.BoatOwner ON dbo.boat.OwnerNo = dbo.BoatOwner.OwnerNo INNER JOIN
dbo.branch ON dbo.boat.BranchNo = dbo.branch.branchno INNER JOIN
dbo.staff ON dbo.branch.branchno = dbo.staff.Branchno
WHERE (dbo.branch.branchAddress LIKE '%LONDON%')
```

But It doesn't work in MYSQL QUERY

How can i convert this into MYSQL QUERY?

Comment: #1142 - SELECT command denied to user ''@'localhost' for table 'boat'

Comment: It appears as though you need SELECT permissions for your user, in this case "@localhot".

Answer (score 0):

You need to know correct table names for MySQL.  Assuming a similar structure, I might try:

```
SELECT b.boatno, b.boattype, s.staffFirstName, s.staffLastName, br.branchAddress
FROM boat b INNER JOIN
     BoatOwner bo
     ON b.OwnerNo = bo.OwnerNo INNER JOIN
     branch br
     ON b.BranchNo = br.branchno INNER JOIN
     staff s
     ON br.branchno = s.Branchno
WHERE br.branchAddress LIKE '%LONDON%';
```

MySQL does not use the three-part naming that SQL Server does.  There is no "schema" in the middle of the name.  The additional periods in the column names are probably one source of confusion.  Using table aliases should work in both databases and makes the code more readable.

Comment: The code works but its listing the same boatNo 11 times? Even though BoatNo is a Unique(PK)

Comment: @user2164535 . . . As I stated in my answer, I don't think this is really the query that you want.  Have you asked another question to better describe what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess from general principles, but perhaps the simpler

```
SELECT A.boatno, A.boattype, D.staffFirstName, D.staffLastName, C.branchAddress
FROM dbo.boat A, dbo.BoatOwner B, dbo.branch C, dbo.staff D
WHERE B.OwnerNo = A.OwnerNo AND C.branchno = A.BranchNo AND D.Branchno = C.branchno
AND C.branchAddress LIKE '%LONDON%'
```

may work.

To begin, make sure also that you can `SELECT` from `dbo.boat`, `dbo.BoatOwner`, `dbo.branch` and `dbo.staff` using your *PHPmyAdmin* environment. Sometimes the simple things trip us up...

Comment: The code works but its listing the same boatNo 11 times? Even though BoatNo is a Unique(PK)

Comment: There was no GROUP BY statement in the initial query, so yes, you can get multiple rows, with the unique/primary key repeating.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT b.boatno, b.boattype, s.staffFirstName, s.staffLastName, br.branchAddress
FROM boat b INNER JOIN
 BoatOwner bo
 ON b.OwnerNo = bo.OwnerNo INNER JOIN
 branch br
 ON b.BranchNo = br.branchno INNER JOIN
 staff s
 ON br.branchno = s.Branchno
WHERE br.branchAddress LIKE '%LONDON%';
GROUP BY b.boatno
```

Isn't that enought?